# jOOQ : compare uuid(from postgresql) and string(user id in class)

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

My backend is postgresql. I am trying to write a simple function to fetch data from database, using jooq records. The DAO for this table is written by me. The problem I am facing is comparison of UUID in db and String provided to function.

```
public Correspondence fetchByExternalId(String externalId) {
    CorrespondenceRecord correspondenceRecord =
            create.fetchOne(Tables.CORRESPONDENCE,
                    Tables.CORRESPONDENCE.USERID.eq(externalId));
```

**CORRESPONDENCE.USERID** is UUID and externalId is String; The operator **eq** is the one which i am not able to implement here, which has worked for me on previous occasions.

The error shown is :
    Cannot resolve method 'eq(java.lang.String)'

when i referred to the [jOOQ site for help](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/comparison-predicate/) it show 'eq' is the operator it suggests to be used!

Can anyone help me with an alternative or tell me where i went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ is a very type safe API, so you cannot compare `UUID` types with `String` types using `eq()`, because the [`eq()` method](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#eq-org.jooq.Field-) uses the generic `<T>` type of your `CORRESPONDENCE.USERID` column, which is `UUID`:

```
TableField<..., java.util.UUID> USERID = ...
```

#### Generating a UUID bind value in the Java client

You either have to supply an `externalId` in the form of a `UUID` type, e.g.:

```
CORRESPONDENCE.USERID.eq(UUID.fromString(externalId))
```

... or, you let jOOQ convert that type for you:

```
CORRESPONDENCE.USERID.eq(CORRESPONDENCE.USERID.getDataType().convert(externalId))
```

Both of the above are equivalent.

#### Generating a UUID bind value in the database

You can always also defer the type conversion work to the database by casting (which will result in a `CAST(? AS UUID)` being rendered:

```
CORRESPONDENCE.USERID.eq(DSL.cast(externalId, UUID.class));
```

... or by coercing the variable to adhere to the `UUID` type (trusting that the database can implicitly convert the `VARCHAR` type to a `UUID` type):

```
CORRESPONDENCE.USERID.eq(DSL.coerce(DSL.val(externalId), UUID.class));
```